# Qt (C++): QFile creates text file successfully but does not write to it

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qtextstream

I have the following code, with which I am attempting to write to a file. When it is called, the file is created in the directory and the `for-loop` is entered. The values for in `QVector<int> program` also exist and are visible with `qDebug()`. However, after I close the file and the window, I check the file on my computer and it is completely empty. I have checked all over StackOverflow and the Qt forums and have yet to find a solution.

```
    QString save_file = "C:/Users/MARVIN/Documents/Saddleback College/2015/Fall/CS3A/Semester Project/Emulator/hello.txt";

    QFile file(save_file);

    if(file.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
    {
        QTextStream out(&save_file);

        out << "hello" << endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            out << program[i] << endl;
            qDebug() << program[i] << endl;
        }

        file.close();
        this->close();
    }
```

Comment: Try a `file.flush()` before you `file.close()`?

Comment: @TheBadger `file.flush()` returns true but it doesn't change the file output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue:

```
QTextStream out(&save_file);
```

should be

```
QTextStream out(&file);
```

Comment: ... Derp, haha. That was so obvious I am kind of embarrassed. I will accept your answer as soon as the time limit is up.

Comment: @Jordan, Took me a few reruns and edits until I finally spotted it, so it is an easy mistake to make